# How to pass mp3 information playing from activity to fragment in android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an app that plays mp3 files load from phone storage. All the mp3 files' infor is saved in to an array. There's an view to display short infor of the playing song on Main Activity and a fragment to display the playing song's details. But I dont know how to pass the playing song details to the fragment.
Here's my code
Add listview and onclick event:

```
        listView = findViewById(R.id.listSong);
    adapter = new Adapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.item_song, mp3List);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                mediaPlayer.release();
            }

            CreateMedia(position);
            mediaPlayer.start();
            btnPlayBottom.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_pause);
            vitri = position;
        }
    });

    btnPlayBottom.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                btnPlayBottom.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_play);
            }
            else{
                mediaPlayer.start();
                btnPlayBottom.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_pause);
            }
        }
    });

    btnNextBottom.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            vitri++;
            if (vitri > (mp3List.size() - 1)){
                vitri = 0;
            }

            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                mediaPlayer.release();
            }
            CreateMedia(vitri);
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    });
```

CreateMedia() function:

```
    public void CreateMedia(int i){
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, Uri.parse(mp3List.get(i).getaPath().toString()));
    txtPlaying.setText(mp3List.get(i).getaName());
    txtAuthor.setText(mp3List.get(i).getaArtist());
}
```

AddFragment() function:

```
    public void AddFragment(View view){
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    Fragment fragment = null;
    int container = 0;

    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.layoutClose:
            fragment = new FragmentClose();
            container = R.id.frameContent;
            break;
        case R.id.layoutList:
            fragment = new FragmentPlaylist();
            container = R.id.frameContent;
            break;
        case R.id.bottomPlayerTouchable:
            fragment = new FragmentPlayer();
            container = R.id.mainFrame;
            break;
    }

    fragmentTransaction.add(container, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("fragment");
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

The frameContent is a part of screen, the mainFrame is full screen.

[Here's the main screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzsOu.png)

[And here's the playing song's detail fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dAGd.jpg)

Please Help!!

Answer (score 0):

You can create public setter functions in respective fragments.
And from activity if you have to pass any info use the fragment objects to pass this info. like below:

```
FragmentA extends Fragment {
 String playingMP = "";
 public void currentMPThree(String mpThree) {
  this.playingMP = mpThree;
 }
}
```

From your activity:

```
FragmentA fragmenta = new FragmentA();
fragmentA.currentMPThree(currentString);
```

Comment: The fragment has not been added into my MainActivity at all. When I tap on my bottom player, the fragment will be added. Then I always get this error java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.myveryfirstapp.FragmentPlayer.SetTimeTotal(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: In that case create the fragments. And reuse them. Also for:
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("fragment");
do use respective fragment name instead of common string for all fragments.